# Vertex AI Managed Notebooks Authentication during Execution

Tags: google-oauth, gcloud, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I created a Managed Notebooks instance using the Compute Engine Service Account. I have some python code which reads from a BigQuery table and does some processing. I did 'gcloud auth application default login', logged into my google account, and then was able to access that BQ table (which otherwise gave access denied error).

Now, I want to run this notebook using the Executor. However, I get access denied errors since the Executor runs the notebook in a tenant project. [This](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/executor) page mentions

```
Also, the executor cannot use end-user credentials to authenticate access to resources, for example, the gcloud auth login command.

To resolve these issues, in your notebook file's code, authenticate access to resources through a service account.

Then when you create an execution or schedule, specify the service account.
```

How do I authenticate access to resources through a service account? I tried setting the compute engine service account as the service account to be used in Executor settings, but it still gives me access denied error for that BQ table. What can I do within my code that is similar to running 'gcloud auth application default login'?

Comment: Can you try following the step 10: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/executor#create-execution here?

Comment: @NestorCenizaJr I did try it with Vertex AI's default service account as well as the compute engine service account. The problem is the service accounts don't have access to these BQ tables for some reason. So I'm trying to find a way of authenticating using user account credentials within the code.

Comment: Can you try giving the service accounts permission to access the datasets? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/control-access-to-resources-iam#grant_access_to_a_dataset

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not in my hands. I'm using BigQuery Scheduled Queries for now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
import google.auth
from google.cloud import storage
credentials, project = google.auth.default()

_GCS_STORAGE_CLIENT = storage.Client(google.auth.default()[1])
```